# Bind multiply Comboboxes to a TextBox

Tags: wpf, events, data-binding, combobox, textbox

I've bound a `ComboBox` to my `TextBox`

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="DescriptionText" Text="{Binding ElementName=ScreenLocations, Path=SelectedItem.Description}" />
```

I have 4 ComboBoxes in my grid. What I want to do is, every time I select an item from any `ComboBox`, update the `TextBox` with the selected objects `Description` property.

Is it possible to bind multiple ComboBoxes to one TextBox, or would I need to use an event of some sort?

Comment: If you added a bit more details, it would be easier for people to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Create a property in your ViewModel and bind all your comboboxes' 'selectedItem' property to it (Use Mode="OneWayToSource", this will prevent changes on selectedItem of one ComboBox to affect the other), then bind your TextBox to the same property created in the VM with Mode="OneWay". Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your VM.

Comment: I'm not 100% how to implement. What type should this property be?  String? And is this property updated to the selected item, thus displaying the description of the item?  Also, if these item in the ComboBoxes are different, will that effect anything? I'm still new to this.

Comment: The property should be of the same type as your combobox items ( I'm supposing all your comboboxes items are of the same type, if not create a parent class and let all the classes of your items inherit from it).